# How inform PhpStorm about method position used in DependencyInjection way, which it "thinks" that doesn't exist?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there any option to inform PhpStorm that method which it says that not exist, is beyond his scope and is defined somewhere else ?

In simpler words:

I have method execution:

`Db::transactional($this)->transactionalUpdate($result);`

I have got method definition also:

```
public function transactionalUpdate(ImportantObjectButNotMuch $baconWithButter)
    {
        echo 'Do a lot of tricks...';
    }
```

Unfortunately PhpStorm doesn't know that execution : `->transactionalUpdate($result);` should run `public function transactionalUpdate`.

Is there any option to write PhpDoc or some other tag to inform it that in case of name refactorization it should change the original function name too ?

P.S. My class structure looks like this:

```
class Db
{
    public static function transactional($object)
    {
        return TransactionalProxy::newInstance($object); //3. It returns ApiObject object 
    }
}

class ApiObject
{
    public function update_record()
    {
        //1. I am starting from there
        $result = new ImportantObjectButNotMuch();
        Db::transactional($this)->transactionalUpdate($result); //2. Next i am passing $this to Db class, to transactional method //4. It should run below transactionalUpdate method
    }

    public function transactionalUpdate(ImportantObjectButNotMuch $baconWithButter)
    {
        echo 'Do a lot of tricks...'; //5. It ends there, it is working but PhpStorm doesn't see it
    }
}
```

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER:**

@Nukeface and @Dmitry caused me to come up with the answer on my Question:
Lets see again into my files structure:

```
class Db
    {
        public static function transactional($object)
        {
            return TransactionalProxy::newInstance($object); //3. It returns ApiObject object 
        }
    }

    class ApiObject
    {
        public function update_record()
        {
            //1. I am starting from there
            $result = new ImportantObjectButNotMuch();
            //EDIT//Db::transactional($this)->transactionalUpdate($result); //2. Next i am passing $this to Db class, to transactional method //4. It should run below transactionalUpdate method
            /** @var self $thisObject */
            //Line above informs PhpStorm that $thisObject is ApiObject indeed
            $thisObject = Db::transactional($this)
            $thisObject->transactionalUpdate($result);
        }

        public function transactionalUpdate(ImportantObjectButNotMuch $baconWithButter)
        {
            echo 'Do a lot of tricks...'; //5. It ends there, it is working but PhpStorm doesn't see it
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `Db::transactional($this)` returns an object that has `transactionalUpdate` method and you want auto-completion for this method?

Comment: Thank You for answer. I have `Db` class which has got `transactional` method, to that method i pass `$this` object which contains `transactionalUpdate` method definition. So i want to inform PhpStorm that `Db::transactional($this)->transactionalUpdate($result);` line refers to method defined in `$this`. Tell me please if it is not clear enough :)

Comment: You can add `@method` phpdoc block to the class of `$this`. https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html

Comment: It is almost what i wanted, but if i think properly there would be demand for that `@method` block if there is no `transactionalUpdate` method  definition in `$this`. I have update files structure in my question. Thank You @Dmitry, if You are out of patience to my question, for Your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of Typehints. Updated your code below:

```
/**
 * Class Db
 * @package Namespace\To\Db
 */
class Db
{

    /**
     * @param $object
     * @return ApiObject (per your line comment)
     */
    public static function transactional($object)
    {
        return TransactionalProxy::newInstance($object); //3. It returns ApiObject object 
    }
}

/**
 * Class ApiObject
 * @package Namespace\To\ApiObject
 */
class ApiObject
{

    /**
     * @return void (I see no "return" statement)
     */
    public function update_record()
    {
        //1. I am starting from there
        $result = new ImportantObjectButNotMuch();
        Db::transactional($this)->transactionalUpdate($result); //2. Next i am passing $this to Db class, to transactional method //4. It should run below transactionalUpdate method
    }

    /**
     * @param ImportantObjectButNotMuch $baconWithButter
     * @return void
     */
    public function transactionalUpdate(ImportantObjectButNotMuch $baconWithButter)
    {
        echo 'Do a lot of tricks...'; //5. It ends there, it is working but PhpStorm doesn't see it
    }
}
```

You can quickly create basic docblocks and typehints by typing `/**` then pressing either "enter" or "space". Enter if you want a docblock and space if you want a typehint.

Examples of own code below:

```
/**
 * Class AbstractEventHandler
 * @package Hzw\Mvc\Event
 */
abstract class AbstractEventHandler implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EventManagerInterface
     */
    protected $events;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager|ObjectManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * AbstractEvent constructor.
     * @param ObjectManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->setEntityManager($entityManager);
    }

    /**
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     */
    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $events->setIdentifiers([
            __CLASS__,
            get_class($this)
        ]);

        $this->events = $events;
    }

    /**
     * @return EventManagerInterface
     */
    public function getEventManager()
    {
        if (!$this->events) {
            $this->setEventManager(new EventManager());
        }

        return $this->events;
    }

    /**
     * @return ObjectManager|EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager|EntityManager $entityManager
     * @return AbstractEventHandler
     */
    public function setEntityManager($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In the above example, PhpStorm knows what every function requires and returns. It knows the types and as some "`return $this`" it knows about the possibility to chain functions.

As an addition, the above code example uses only "docblocks". Below some "inline typehints" from within a function. Especially useful when it's not going to be immediately clear what is going to be returned. That way, again, PhpStorm knows from where to get functions, options, etc. to show you.

```
/** @var AbstractForm $form */
$form = $this->getFormElementManager()->get($formName, (is_null($formOptions) ? [] : $formOptions));

/** @var Request $request */
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

As a final hint. If you create a bunch of properties for a class, such as in my example `protected $events` or `protected $entityManager`, you can also generate the getters & setters. If your properties contain the docblocks, it will also generate the docblocks for you on these functions.

E.g. the property below

```
/**
 * @var EntityManager|ObjectManager
 */
protected $entityManager;
```

When using "Alt + Insert" you get a menu at cursor location. Choose "Getters/Setters". In the pop-up, select "entityManager" and check the box at the bottom for "fluent setters". Then the code below is generated for you:

```
/**
 * @return ObjectManager|EntityManager
 */
public function getEntityManager()
{
    return $this->entityManager;
}

/**
 * @param ObjectManager|EntityManager $entityManager
 * @return AbstractEventHandler
 */
public function setEntityManager($entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closes thing you can do to what you want to do is to use `@return` with multiple types.

```
/**
 * @param $object
 * @return ApiObject|AnotherApiObject|OneMoreApiObject
 */
public static function transactional($object)
{
    return TransactionalProxy::newInstance($object);
}
```