# Netbeans variable hinting using a service locator

Tags: netbeans, zend-framework2, service-locator

Zend Framework 2 utilises a service locator, which I am using to load table classes from.

Instead of writing `$table = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\TableName');` I have written a helper function `$this->getTable($tableName);` where I only have to supply the class name, for example `UserTable`, and the function prefixes with the namespace before calling the service locator and `get`ting the model.

In my controller, when I call `$table = $this->getTable($tableName);` how can I get the `vdoc` command to populate `$table` with the resolved namespace and class name of `$tableName` instead of `ServiceLocator`.

```
/**
 * Get the requested model.
 * @param string $tableName
 * @return Application\Model\AbstractTable
 */
public function getTable($tableName) {
    return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\\'.$tableName);
}
```

Netbeans has a variable-doc shortcode `vdoc` that is automatically populated with the variable and class name.

What I'm getting at the moment:

```
//typing vdoc creates this
/* @var $table ServiceLocatorInterface */
$table = $this->getTable('UserTable');
```

What I want:

```
/* @var $table Application\Model\UserTable */
$table = $this->getTable('UserTable');
```

I suspect I need to specify the variable being returned in the `getTable` function, but how do I do that dynamically?

e.g.

```
/* @var $model Application\Model\{@@@$tableName} */
```

Comment: I have normally added the comment above the variable to achieve what you want, exactly like you done in your question. Does adding this `/* @var $table Application\Model\UserTable */` line above the `$table` line does not work for you or it is working, but you only want a dynamic solution.

Comment: I'm looking for a dynamic solution, so when I type `vdoc` netbeans will automatically use the correct namespace / class

Comment: Why are you not using the class FQCN's for passing what you want to the SM? If you register your classes and factories in the `'service_manager' => [ 'factories' => [ {...} ],],` (key/value pairs in `{...}`) config, you could simply do `$container->get(MyClass::class)` (or `$this->getServiceLocator()->get(MyClass::class)` in a Factory). You should not be using `$this->getServiceLocator()` in a Controller (or elsewhere in a not Factory), no matter whether or not this is in a wrapper/helper function or not...

Comment: For your type hinting though, [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46302572/1155833) something like what you're looking for? In PhpStorm the type-hint blocks start with `/**` instead of `/*`, then using a `space` or `Enter` will create the block you need because it knows, or it will create a block in which you still need to define the type (after `@var`)